# ASP.Net Core Identity ResetPasswordAsync Failed : InvalidToken

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to create a function that will reset the users password when requested in [asp .net core 3.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-1/) using [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)
So far whenever the function `GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync` is called it returns the token as expected

```
// Generate Reset Token.
var token = await userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(appIdentityUser);
```

`CfDJ8OHfQcgoimpKvwzwyqjhuwNuJOOwPXPw2F9wg5t7HNMc+YZbnJn1n8cVwBmq/yYV4edV8wl+p6QHSOv/gtW6yat7iuD9v9dBqTmw+Lie2UY9MDLsMEu+GQWaRlUWEH70FoyGqUUcU1/Tzk6tmBvz8cRPlx2KTnJfVc73e1XMZg69pUk58XRuKzRTgwyw/70aSSy6oh1LgDj4g1OqPRSqsgKaPh1vUnMThYb0GwqovqGZoU37N5COem4RmYFn4uVIEQ==`

For testing purposes I am now calling the `ResetPasswordAsync` within the same method to see if the password will reset 
NOTE `user` is found.

```
// Find User.
AppIdentityUser user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(appIdentityUser.Email);

// Attempt To Reset The Password To someRealL0ngP@ssW0rd
IdentityResult resetPassword = await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, "someRealL0ngP@ssW0rd");
```

Unfortunately I receive this error `Failed : InvalidToken`

Here is `AddIdentity` that is in the startup file along with the `DbContext`.

```
...
// Create The DbContext.
services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AussieFoods2ULocal"));
});

// Identity User. Plus Password Complexity For Easy Testing.
services.AddIdentity<AppIdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

 // Paths For The Identity
 services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
 {
     options.LoginPath = "/Security/SignIn";
     options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Security/AccessDenided";
 });
    
 services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
 {
      options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
 });

 services.AddAuthentication();
 ...
```

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it, but I did create a custom class that inherits from [IdentityUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn468178(v%3Dvs.108))

```
public class AppIdentityUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    [EmailAddress]
    [Required]
    public override string Email { get => base.Email; set => base.Email = value; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Suburb { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `FindByEmailAsync` when you already have `appIdentityUser`? Aren't `user` and `appIdentityUser` the same?

Comment: I’m calling it because the userid is missing for when you call the ResetPasswordAsync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test your Startup.cs config, I quickly made a new project. The `ConfigureServices` was the same as yours with `services.AddControllersWithViews();` at the end and `Configure` looks liked below.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

I then created an action to create a user and reset the password. Below is the action to reset the password.

```
public async Task ResetPassword()
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync("your-email-address@domain.com");
    var token = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
    var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
}
```

This returns a successful result.

Answer (score 3):

If you're sending an email with something like Sendgrid and using HtmlContent to link the token, I found that all instances of "+" are replaced with " " for whatever reason.

The simple solution to this is to do a string.Replace.

```
var decodedToken = token.Replace(" ", "+");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an custom token provider to generate `PasswordResetToken` like this

```
public class ResetPasswordTokenProvider<TUser> : DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser> where TUser : class
{
    public ResetPasswordTokenProvider(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider,
        IOptions<ResetPasswordTokenProviderOptions> options)
        : base(dataProtectionProvider, options)
    {
    }
}
public class ResetPasswordTokenProviderOptions : DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions
{
    public ResetPasswordTokenProviderOptions()
    {
        Name = "ResetPasswordDataProtectorTokenProvider";
        TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    }
}
```

Then register custom token provider in `AddIdentity` and `services`

```
services.AddIdentity<AppIdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    //NOTE THIS
    options.Tokens.ProviderMap.Add("ResetPassword", new TokenProviderDescriptor(typeof(ResetPasswordTokenProvider<AppIdentityUser>)));
    options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = "ResetPassword";

})
.AddTokenProvider<ResetPasswordTokenProvider<AppUserIdentity>>("ResetPassword")//<--NOTE THIS
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>();
```