ASP.NET Core Identity ResetPasswordAsync fails with InvalidToken error
I am using ASP.NET Core Identity to manage users in my application. Currently, I am trying to implement a password reset functionality. I generate a password reset token and send it to the user. However, when I use the received token to reset the password, I get an InvalidToken error.
Here is the relevant part of my code:
public async Task<string> GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(UserEntity user)
{
    var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
    return token;
}

public async Task<ErrorOr<UserEntity>> ResetPasswordAsync(UserEntity user, string token, string password)
{
    var resetPasswordResult = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, password);

    if (resetPasswordResult.Succeeded)
    {
        return user;
    }
    else
    {
        return Error.Validation(resetPasswordResult.Errors.FirstOrDefault()!.Description.ToString());
    }
}

 [HttpPost("reset-password")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPasswordAsync([FromBody] ResetPasswordRequest request)
    {
        var resetPasswordResult = await _mediatr.Send(
            _mapper.Map<ResetPasswordCommand>(request));

        return resetPasswordResult.Match(
            resetPasswordResult => Ok(),
            errors => Problem(errors));
    }

public record ResetPasswordRequest
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{PropertyName} must not be empty")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "{PropertyValue} has wrong format")]
    [Length(5, 254)]
    public required string Email { get; init; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{PropertyName} must not be empty")]
    [Length(256, 4096)]
    public required string Token { get; init; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{PropertyName} must not be empty")]
    [Length(8, 24)]
    public required string Password { get; init; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{PropertyName} must not be empty")]
    [Compare("Password",
        ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    [Length(8, 24)]
    public required string ConfirmPassword { get; init; }
}

 public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> ResetPasswordAsync(
      TUser user,
      string token,
      string newPassword)
    {
      this.ThrowIfDisposed();
      ArgumentNullThrowHelper.ThrowIfNull((object) user, nameof (user));
      if (!await this.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, this.Options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider, "ResetPassword", token).ConfigureAwait(false))
        return IdentityResult.Failed(this.ErrorDescriber.InvalidToken());
      IdentityResult identityResult = await this.UpdatePasswordHash(user, newPassword, true).ConfigureAwait(false);
      return !identityResult.Succeeded ? identityResult : await this.UpdateUserAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
public async Task<ErrorOr<Success>> SendResetPasswordEmailAsync(
        string email, string token, string baseUrl, string userName)
    {
        string url = $"{baseUrl}/authentication/reset-password/{email}/{WebUtility.UrlEncode(token)}";

        string emailBody = string.Empty;

        using (StreamReader reader = new("./EmailTemplates/forgot-password.html"))
        {
            emailBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        emailBody = emailBody.Replace("{{ name }}", userName);

        emailBody = emailBody.Replace("{{ url }}", url);

        await _smtpService.SendEmailAsync(email, "Reset password", emailBody);

        return Result.Success;
    }


Debug Information:
Password: Qwerty123*
Token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ..."
User: test@gmail.com

The token is generated correctly, and I ensure not to modify it before using it in the ResetPasswordAsync method. However, the method still fails with the InvalidToken error.

Found a similar thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62590882/asp-net-core-identity-resetpasswordasync-failed-invalidtoken
